# Adding two window onclick functions not executing Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a hamburger menu using pure javascript.

I have one window.onclick function is supposed to collapse the menu when you click outside of it, that is working fine by itself.

However, when I add another one, they both stops working. I've changed variable names but its not working

Here is What I've done, for a full copy of the code please visit https://jsfiddle.net/7wcyz9p5/

```
var navcontainerwrapperr = document.getElementById('main_wrapper_box');

 window.onclick = function(eventexi) {
if (eventexi.target == navcontainerwrapperr) {
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}

//// if these below lines are removed it works fine 
//// if these below lines are removed it works fine
var ciever = document.getElementById('bix');

window.onclick = function(eventexit) {
if (eventexit.target == ciever) {
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

Comment: You should only have 1 window.onclick function. Use an else statement `if (parameter.target == main_wrapper) { do stuff; } else { do other stuff; }`

Comment: fiddle is not working (syntax error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add more than one listener on "onclick" event you, probably, should use 'addEventListener' rather than onclick function, because if you use property 'onclick' that means that after you assign first function and try to assign second you just rewrite the first:

```
var navcontainerwrapperr = document.getElementById('main_wrapper_box');
window.addEventListener('click',function(eventexi) {
    if (eventexi.target == navcontainerwrapperr) {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    }
});

var ciever = document.getElementById('bix');

window.addEventListener('click', function(eventexit) {
    if (eventexit.target == ciever) {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    }
});
```

But in your case it is also more convenient to use one click listener with if-else inside:

```
var navcontainerwrapperr = document.getElementById('main_wrapper_box');
var ciever = document.getElementById('bix');
window.addEventListener('click',function(eventexi) {
    if (eventexi.target == navcontainerwrapperr) {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    } 
    if (eventexit.target == ciever) {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I've got window.onclick fucntions all over my website its probably best to use listener :)

Answer (score 1):

This works, See the updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/vineeshmp/7wcyz9p5/2/

```
var navcontainerwrapperr = document.getElementById('main_wrapper_box');

var menu = document.getElementById('menu');

var closebtn = document.getElementById('closebtn');
window.onclick = function(eventexi) {
    if (eventexi.target == navcontainerwrapperr) {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    }

    if (eventexi.target == menu) {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "300px";
    }
    if (eventexi.target == closebtn) {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a missing "}" in the first window.onclick function. Also, I've clicked on the javascript engine and changed the load type from **onLoad** to **no warp head**

Check the updated url https://jsfiddle.net/7wcyz9p5/5/

```
window.onclick = function(eventexi) {
    if (eventexi.target == navcontainerwrapperr) {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    }
}
```